# Editorconfig indent C# record properties

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting, editorconfig

I am trying to use editorconfig + ReSharper/cleanupcode.exe to format my C# code (using [this cool precommit hook](https://github.com/GeeWee/resharper-pre-commit-hook))

The problem I am having is that cleanupcode refuses to indent properties in a `record`

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public record MyRecord
    {
    // I would like these to be indented
    public int Property1 { get; init; }
    public int Property2 { get; init; }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Property1 { get; init; }
        public int Property2 { get; init; }
    }
}
```

Here is my editorconfig file

```
root = true

# top-most EditorConfig file

# Don't use tabs for indentation.
[*]
indent_style = space

# ReSharper properties
resharper_place_accessor_attribute_on_same_line = true

# Code files
[*.{cs,csx,vb,vbx}]
indent_size = 4
insert_final_newline = true
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
csharp_indent_block_contents = true
csharp_max_line_length = 150
```

Does anyone know what setting/rule I need to set to make editorconfig/ReSharper indent these record properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only tested your settings in Rider and the properties are getting highlighted as you'd like to.

The mentioned tool is pretty old (`v2019.3.1`, [see here](https://github.com/GeeWee/resharper-pre-commit-hook/blob/master/install-git-hook.sh#L15)) - at that time, `record`s didn't even exist in C#.

Try it with a newer version: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/CleanupCode.html

Comment: This makes so much sense and solves my problem! For others looking at this, make sure to perform the "Unblock" step in the CleanUpCode Command-Line Tool instructions.